# smtpdiag tool lists wrong mail servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp, mx-record

I have a weird issue on a server. When i run the smtpdiag tool, it lists the old mail server settings (with mx servers being **website.com & mx01.1and1.com**). here're the results

```
Checking MX servers listed for help@website.com.
Connecting to website.com [50.*.*.*] on port 25.
Successfully connected to website.com.
Connecting to mx01.1and1.com [74.208.5.21] on port 25.
Successfully connected to mx01.1and1.com.
```

when i run the smtpdiag on my laptop, it shows the new settings (**mx01.1and1.com & mx00.1and1.com**)

```
Checking MX servers listed for help@website.com. Connecting to
mx01.1and1.com [74.208.5.21] on port 25. Successfully connected to
mx01.1and1.com. Connecting to mx00.1and1.com [74.208.5.3] on port 25.
Successfully connected to mx00.1and1.com.
```

I've tried ipconfig /flushdns, i've tried to restart the smtp service, iis, and even the server, but it's stuck with the old records. please advise. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS may need 24h or more to be updated and propagated through all levels of caching. This might be perfectly normal. Try again in a day, or query authoritative DNS servers directly.

Comment: yep that's what it was. although i'm not sure why i couldn't force the cache to clear

Comment: There are multiple levels of caches. Your DNS Servers may be caching as well, not only your client.